# Show small numbers as percent's by default pandas

Tags: python, pandas, format

Is there a way to change the default in pandas to show columns as percent if all values in column is less then 1?

Comment: I want to say no because percent in the df is shown as a string format, except you just want to save the column element as a string.

Comment: if you just want to check out the content in string way, you can try `df.applymap(lambda x: f'{x*100:0.2f}%' if (isinstance(x, float) and 0 <= x <= 1) else x)`